# Set Range Based on Last Cell with Value Plus 1

Tags: vba, excel

For reasons beyond my control, I must save and upload my data as a csv and i must manually select and clear the cells below my data set, the range changes daily.

**Question**: How can I edit my vba script to create a range based on the cell below my data set to :J10 and clear/delete it? 
EDIT: Are there any changes you would implement?

Here's what I currently have, after exporting and saving as a csv, I reopen the new data and sort and attempt to clear. I have already tried `Selection.SpecialCells(CellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.ClearContents` & `Selection.SpecialCells(CellTypeBlanks).ClearContents`

I have 5 separate csv workbooks this macro currently opens and operates on but here is the final portion of my script that is giving me errors

```
 Sub openCSV()
    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
        If ActiveSheet.Range("H" & i).Value = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(i).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i

    Range("A2:J10").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BA").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BA").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("H2") _
                                                              , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BA").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A2:J10")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    On Error Resume Next
    Range("A2:H10").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(CellTypeBlanks).ClearContents
    Range("A2:J10").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(CellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.ClearContents

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
    SaveChanges = True
```

Thank you for your time and assistance

Comment: Get rid of the On Error Resume Next and the .Select. Add a countblank test to see if blanks present before attempting specialcells.

Comment: What are the errors? And on which lines? See [avoid .Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and [finding last row](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm)

Comment: When uploading to our server, it states lines 7&8 are corrupt, which correspond to the lines filled prior to data removal

Comment: So is your code working, but the upload isn't?

Comment: Code works fine, Upload throws corruption errors. I got it to work by saving after sorting, closing the new csv, reopening and then attempting the SpecialCell.ClearContents. 

Uploads fine with the reopen